# Electrumx protocol

Tags: electrum

The [description](https://electrumx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocol-basics.html#script-hashes) states:

```
A script hash is the hash of the binary bytes of the locking script (ScriptPubKey), expressed as a hexadecimal string. The hash function to use is given by the “hash_function” member of server.features() (currently sha256() only). Like for block and transaction hashes, when converting the big-endian binary hash to a hexadecimal string the least-significant byte appears first, and the most-significant byte last.

For example, the legacy Bitcoin address from the genesis block:

1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa
has P2PKH script:

76a91462e907b15cbf27d5425399ebf6f0fb50ebb88f1888ac
with SHA256 hash:

6191c3b590bfcfa0475e877c302da1e323497acf3b42c08d8fa28e364edf018b
which is sent to the server reversed as:

8b01df4e368ea28f8dc0423bcf7a4923e3a12d307c875e47a0cfbf90b5c39161
By subscribing to this hash you can find P2PKH payments to that address.
```

Can anybody explain what these numbers are:

**6191c3b590bfcfa0475e877c302da1e323497acf3b42c08d8fa28e364edf018b**

**8b01df4e368ea28f8dc0423bcf7a4923e3a12d307c875e47a0cfbf90b5c39161**

and how to get them?

Answer (score 2):

Using the [bx command line tool](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer),
the Satoshi address:

`1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa`

looks like this decoded (using bx)

```
$ bx base58-decode 1A1zP1eP5QGefi2DMPTfTL5SLmv7DivfNa
```

outputs:

```
0062e907b15cbf27d5425399ebf6f0fb50ebb88f18c29b7d93
```

The first 2 digits (`00`) is the version number, the last 8 digits (`c29b7d93`) is the checksum. Leaving `62e907b15cbf27d5425399ebf6f0fb50ebb88f18` as your payload (pubkey in this instance).

Now if I were to make a basic P2PKH locking script with the above pubkey it would look like this:

```
dup hash160 [62e907b15cbf27d5425399ebf6f0fb50ebb88f18] equalverify checksig
```

and now encode it in base16:

```
bx script-encode "dup hash160 [62e907b15cbf27d5425399ebf6f0fb50ebb88f18] equalverify checksig"
```

result:

```
76a91462e907b15cbf27d5425399ebf6f0fb50ebb88f1888ac
```

sha256 this:

```
bx sha256 76a91462e907b15cbf27d5425399ebf6f0fb50ebb88f1888ac
```

result is your number:

```
6191c3b590bfcfa0475e877c302da1e323497acf3b42c08d8fa28e364edf018b
```

The second number,

```
8b01df4e368ea28f8dc0423bcf7a4923e3a12d307c875e47a0cfbf90b5c39161
```

is [serialized in the little-endian](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/ch06.asciidoc#transaction-serializationoutputs) (least-significant-byte-first) order. As stated in the link:

> When transactions are transmitted over the network or exchanged between applications, they are serialized. Serialization is the process of converting the internal representation of a data structure into a format that can be transmitted one byte at a time, also known as a byte stream. Serialization is most commonly used for encoding data structures for transmission over a network or for storage in a file.

so they're the same number, except byte by byte backwards (I exploded the last 3 bytes of the first to make it apparent).

```
6191c3b590bfcfa0475e877c302da1e323497acf3b42c08d8fa28e364e df 01 8b
8b 01 df ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!
One more question: we derived this number :
```76a91462e907b15cbf27d5425399ebf6f0fb50ebb88f1888ac```
from P2PKH:
```62e907b15cbf27d5425399ebf6f0fb50ebb88f18```
by adding a prefix ```76a914``` and suffix ```88ac```.
What are these prefix and suffix? Do they depend on currency or something else?

Comment: It's not derived from `62e9..` but its making a locking script using that pubkey, then encoding it. So you're seeing the base16 encoding of the script language. For example, `bx script-encode "[62e907b15cbf27d5425399ebf6f0fb50ebb88f18]"` yields the hash `1462e907b15cbf27d5425399ebf6f0fb50ebb88f18` (14...) and `bx script-encode "dup hash160 equalverify checksig"` yields `76a988ac`. The pubkey is already base16, of course. So there are your numbers.